# I want to take an StopLoss as Previous 7 Candles Low from the candle of entry but my Stoploss gets changed every new entry get triggered

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
var float SL_at_entry = na

SL = ta.lowest(7)

is_new_long = (strategy.position_size > 0) and (strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1])
is_new_short = (strategy.position_size < 0) and (strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1])
is_new_entry = is_new_long or is_new_short

SL_at_entry := is_new_entry ? SL[1] : SL_at_entry


LongStopLoss = SL_at_entry
LongTarget = (strategy.position_avg_price + 220)
```

here I want to take an sl of previous 7 candles low from entry but sl is dynamic and changes in every new entry condition. How can I do it?